# Trying to generate a large-scale test data set with Bogus

Tags: c#, testing, data-generation, bogus

I'm trying to generate a production-quality and -quantity size test data set with [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus), and this library works extremely well with basic data - simple datatypes like `int` or `string`, things like first and last name etc.

I'm currently not seeing how I can handle two scenarios in my test data setup:

- for certain attributes of an object, I'd like to be able to define something like "in 20-30% of the cases, use a `NULL` instead of generating a value" - is this possible somehow?
- in other cases, I need to randomly pick an object from a list of available objects - but I need to use that one, picked object to set more than one attribute on my object being generated. E.g. for an "order", I might want to pick a "City" from a given list of possible cities - and once I have a city, I want to set the `CityName`, `State` and `ZipCode` of my "order" object from that one, selected city. I haven't found a way to do this (yet) - any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To provide null sometimes you can just pick random number in 0-100 range and generate value only if it's above threshold:

  ```
  // generate null in 30% of cases
  RuleFor(o => o.Item, f => f.Random.Number(0, 100) >= 30 ? f.Name.FullName() : null)
  ```
- To use picked object - just use this property in followup rule:

  ```
  // u in lambda represents whole object
  RuleFor(o => o.City, f => f.PickRandom(cities)).
  RuleFor(o => o.CityName, (f, u) => u.City.Name)
  ```

Comment: There are helper methods in `Bogus.Extensions` called `.OrNull()`/`.OrDefault()` that accept a probability of generating a null/default value. `RuleFor(o => o.Item, f => f.Name.FullName().OrNull(f, .30f))`